# Blend Slider Control

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

Is there a free implementation of the text box in Blend's property grid that allows you to change the number by clicking and dragging?  Or perhaps another way to ask is what kind of control called so I can google it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try this

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MicrosoftBlendStyleTextBo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's called a numeric UpDown control. (Terrible name, I know).

MS has a [sample implementation for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771573.aspx), although I think you'll have to provide the draggable part yourself.